# Blender не запекает OpenVDB

Tags: blender

Пытаюсь запечь дым в Blender 2.79 , если ставлю галочку external то пишет что no valid data to read. 
Процесс запекания проходит, но папка с кешем пустая. 
Куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

1. Cтавим галочку `external`: видим сообщение `valid data to read` - не обращаем внимания
2. Выбираем путь куда сохранять кеш, ставим первый и последний кадр (сколько надо кеша) и жмем Bake.
3. Видим сообщение `XX frames found`